# ffmpeg add subtitle from a variable and not a file

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I would like to add a subtitle to a short video clip but my subtitle is in a variable and not in a file.

Is there a way to do that? Something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "subtitles='$title':force_style='Fontsize=24,PrimaryColour=&H0000ff&'" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

(which is not working of course as ffmpeg asks for a file)

I also tried to use drawtext instead but my subtitle needs to be wrapped.

Comment: Do you have [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)?

Comment: @dawg no but I can install it. I'm running Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this, but something like this should work:

```
subtitle="subtitles='$title':force_style='Fontsize=24,PrimaryColour=&H0000ff&'"
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf <<<"$subtitle" -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Where the variable is fed into the command as a here-string. I'm not 100% on the syntax tho', but I'll test this out later.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can create the effect of a file with `<(  )` in Bash.

Example, `cat` only takes file inputs. You can get a variable to act like a file like so:

```
$ var="this is a var"
$ cat <(echo "$var")
this is a var
```

I don't have `ffmpeg` installed to test, but if the argument requires a file and you have a string you can try that.

You can also just redirect a string to a file and then use that:

```
$ echo "$var" > /tmp/file
$ cat /tmp/file
this is a var
```

If ffmpeg is prompting you to input a file name, you can try using [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).